Flutter web widget test fails after showing "All tests passed"
I am encountering an issue where a widget with a specific ValueKey is not found during a widget test, even though the widget exists in the widget tree. The interactions in the test work perfectly, and the componentsTable widget is visible and tapped by WidgetTester. Despite this, the test fails with the following error message:
Expected: exactly one matching candidate
  Actual: _KeyWidgetFinder:<Found 0 widgets with key [<'componentsTable'>]: []>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

Things to note:

The error shows up after "All tests passed!" is printed to the console
The error shows only after the test is complete, not when the widget is encountered.
Platform: web

pubspec.yaml
name: project
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.2.3 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  collection: ^1.18.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.2
  firebase_core: ^3.2.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.6
  flutter_markdown: ^0.7.3+1
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  go_router: ^14.2.0
  google_identity_services_web: ^0.3.1+1
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  http: ^1.2.1
  intl: ^0.19.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.4
  localstorage: ^5.0.0
  logger: ^2.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  super_extensions: ^0.0.7
  universal_html: ^2.2.4
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  animated_custom_dropdown: ^3.1.1
  rxdart: ^0.28.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mocktail: ^1.0.4

dependency_overrides:
  meta: ^1.12.0
  intl: ^0.19.0
  http: ^1.2.1

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
  uses-material-design: true


Environment:
Flutter version: 3.24.2
Dart version: 3.5.2
Operating system: MAC OS 15.2 Beta
Why is the widget with the ValueKey('componentsTable') not being found during the test, even though it is visible and can be interacted with? How can I resolve this issue?

I tried to run in multiple versions of Flutter, but the error still occurs
Tried adding many calls to tester.pump() and tester.pumpAndSettle() before the line where the exception had occurred
Tried puting ensureVisible() too.

